# sql symfony entity relationship orm for movie database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I am developing a movie database app with symfony and facing few problems.

I have one entity content(movie):

```
Bbd\MyAppBundle\Entity\Content:
type: entity
repositoryClass: Bbd\MyAppBundle\Repository\ContentRepository
table: content
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    title:
        type: string
        length: 120
        unique: true
....
```

Then I have Artist :

```
Bbd\MyAppBundle\Entity\Artist:
type: entity
table: artist
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    name:
        type: string
        length: 255
        unique: true
```

Then I have role:

```
type: entity
table: role
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    name: ~
```

Now, One content will have many roles, like: Actor, Actress, Director.. One Artist may have many role within one content. Now i dont know how can i build the relational entity table. I would like to have a cast table where content_id, role_id, artist_id will be saved.

the next issue is i want to enter all data from content form, where I would like to have all roles from db will be displayed as HTML label and next to it artist name box dropdown. I really have no clue how can i do that. is there any suggestion or have better user friendly gui?

Comment: You have this question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692163/symfony2-many-to-many-relational-db-structure

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Doctrine2 with the YAML configuration format.

What you want to achieve is a common use case and it is documented pretty good here:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

There is always a "YAML"-tab on the snippets.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am also having same kind of issue. but you see there are three tables in relation with differently. Like content to role oneToMany, role to artist manyToMany, so we must need a join table to handle all relation. how can we join these three and make another table any idea?

Comment: Using manyToMany the doctrine schema updater will create a join table for you, once you got the configuration right.

Comment: finger crossed I know how to join two tables but as im not good at db don't know how to join three tables can you me a small example..:p

Comment: All you need is manyToMany, oneToMany, and manyToOne. I can't help you with your use case as the design seems flawed to me and I don't get what you are trying to achieve. I assure you that you do not need a join table for 3 things. Of course your entity can have more than one manyToOne relation. Please read the docs!